# Excluding basis in tensor notation

Tags: tensors

My question is: is there anywhere in tensors that we lose something by dropping the basis, or where it makes something more difficult? Like by saying the a tensor $T^{ij}e_i\otimes e_j$ is represented entirely by the notation $T^{ij}$?

Another thing, because there is only one i and j in the previous expression, does the summation convention kick in?

I heard this on the YouTube channel XylyXylyX (that's actually the name). Correct me if this is wrong because I've just started learning this myself.

Comment: You might find part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3044280/39599) helpful.

Comment: @Michael Albanese Thanks, which part exactly?

Comment: @Michael Albanese also it's confusing me that in one case $T^{ij}$ is a tensor valued quantity and in the other it's a scalar quantity being summed over.

Comment: Basically all of it. $T^{ij}$ is not a tensor-valued quantity. As is mentioned in the answer below, $T^{ij}$ are the coefficients of the tensor with respect to a fixed basis of the vector space. If the basis changes, the coefficients change in a certain way. Often in physics, people regard the collection of coefficients $T^{ij}$, together with the knowledge of how it transforms under a change of basis, as the tensor itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking $\mathbf T^{ij}$ represents the $(i,j)$th component of the $(2,0)$ tensor $\mathbf T$ relative to a particular basis of $V \times V$, and the whole tensor would be represented by

$\mathbf T^{ij} \mathbf e_i \otimes \mathbf e_j$

which is short for

$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbf T^{ij} \mathbf e_i \otimes \mathbf e_j$

But $\mathbf T^{ij}$ is often used informally to represent all of the $n^2$ components of $\mathbf T$.

Comment: So when used informally do you treat $T^{ij}$ as a tensor or a scalar when manipulating it? Don't you lose some information when dropping the basis?

Comment: Oh, nevermind you can use diacritics to show a different basis, and T refers to the whole tensor without a specific basis as an invariant object.